# Using A* for meal planning

Tags: search, optimization, a-star

I want to generate a meal plan consisting of 3 meals, one of the meals are already chosen. 
A target for these 3 meals could be 3000 calories and a cooking time on 180 min.
These 3 meals should be as close to the target as possible.

I have a problem with implementing A*. I can't figure out how to translate the usual grid to a graph of recipes. And how this "path" should be generated.

Comment: Me neither. Why are you planning to use A* for this?

Comment: I just wanted to learn A* and wanted to use it in a bit different way. Do you have any suggestion for which algorithm to use?